# Migrating from Ionic 3 to Ionic 5 - Json functions on user-data

Tags: json, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Hello i am trying to migrate from Ionic Cordova 3 to 5.
I want to put a call a php function to get results. PHP works fine.

this is what i did to call the results.

home.ts

```
allMediaSet(){
console.log('dddd1');
this.offset = 0;
this.userData.allMedias(this.offset)
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(data => {

  if (data.success) {
    this.allMedia = data.mediaFeed;
  }
}); 
}
```

user-data.ts function

```
 allMedias(offset: number) {
    console.log('ddd');
    let url = this.appData.getApiUrl() + 'allMedia';

    let data = this.jsonToURLEncoded({
        api_signature: this.api_signature,
        offset: offset
    });
    return this.http.post(url, data, this.options);

}
```

this is the error i am getting
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Platform]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Platform]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Platform!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Platform]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Platform]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Platform!

app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx'; 
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
   Platform,
  HttpClientModule,
  FormsModule,
  IonicModule.forRoot(),
  IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
  ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
    enabled: environment.production
  })
],
declarations: [AppComponent],
providers: [InAppBrowser, SplashScreen, StatusBar],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

login.ts (has the results i want to return)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserData } from '../../providers/user-data/user-data';

import { UserOptions } from '../../interfaces/user-options';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.scss'],
})
 export class LoginPage {

resposeData: any;
loginData: any = {};
allMedia:any =[];
 mediaType:string = '';
 offset: number = 0;

login: UserOptions = { username: '', password: '' };
submitted = false;

 constructor(
   public userData: UserData,
   public router: Router,
 ) 
 { 
  this.allMediaSet();
 }


 allMediaSet(){
  console.log('dddd1');
   this.offset = 0;
   this.userData.allMedias(this.offset)
  .subscribe(data => {

   console.log(data);
  }); 
 }

  onLogin(form: NgForm) {
  this.submitted = true;

  if (form.valid) {
    this.userData.login(this.login.username);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/app/tabs/schedule');
   }
 }
```

}

any help?

Comment: That error tells you you didn't provide `Platform` in your module. It has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems like not Ionic specific but it is about Angular. Since good old Ionic 3 / Angular 4 days, Angular moved on from Http to HttpClient.

Please see here: https://angular.io/guide/http#setup

You need to ensure you migrate your Angular code to use the latest HttpClientModule:

https://devops.datenkollektiv.de/migrating-from-angular-httpmodule-to-new-angular-43-httpclientmodule.html

In short:

replace 'Http' with 'HttpClient':

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
```

becomes

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Remove manual extraction of JSON via map operator:

```
this.userData.allMedias(this.offset).map(res => res.json())
```

becomes

```
this.userData.allMedias(this.offset)
```

Comment: ok now i am getting 'property success does noe exist on type Response' if (data.success) {
        this.allMedia = data.mediaFeed;
      }

Comment: can you post console.log of "data" in your case?

Comment: it doesn't return anything Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'Platform' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation. and i have platform on NgModule in app.module.ts import { Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    Platform,

Comment: OK please share extracts of your code from app.module.ts and the component module + full relevant code of the component